# ToggleSplitButton IsChecked property not working... possible bug?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using the ToggleSplitButton for the first time and I found a possible bug: it seems that this control can't accept a normal property for the two-way binding with IsChecked property.

I found this strange behaviour both in the `windows.ui.xaml.controls.ToggleSplitButton` (the native control, provided with Visual Studio itself) and in the `microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.ToggleSplitButton` (the same control, but from the WinUI nuget package).

This is the code, used as in the XAML Controls Gallery...

```
<ToggleSplitButton VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{x:Bind ThemeViewModel.IsLeftPaneTransparent, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid/>
    </StackPanel>

    <ToggleSplitButton.Flyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
            <Grid/>
        </Flyout>
    </ToggleSplitButton.Flyout>
</ToggleSplitButton>
```

...this is my property, in my ThemeViewModel cs file...

```
private bool isLeftPaneTransparent;
public Boolean IsLeftPaneTransparent
{
    get { return isLeftPaneTransparent; }
    set { SetProperty(ref isLeftPaneTransparent, value); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsNOTLeftPaneTransparent)); }
}
```

...and this is the error I get:

> TwoWay binding target 'IsChecked' must be a dependency property

Do the *native* ToggleSplitButton support twoway binding for its primary property (IsChecked)?
And the one from WinUI package is also not supporting twoway binding?
Is there any way to avoid using the IsCheckedChanged method?
I also tried to set the *minimum* version for my app to 1903 (before it was set to 1809), but the error still continues to stop the debugging from starting.

This new XAML control was so useful for my scenario, but it seems that Microsoft always forgets doing something.

I suspect that it is Microsoft fault because I remember that even the new TreeView control, in Win 10 1709, couldn't support data binding, beeing added in Win 10 1803.
Maybe this control is still in development...

Regards

Comment: _"I found a possible bug"_ -- unlikely. _"seems that Microsoft always forgets doing something"_ -- nobody is perfect, but frankly, it's much more likely that you forgot to do something than that Microsoft did. That said, as far as this question goes, the error message seems clear to me. Targets of bindings must be dependency properties. You say you're not using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSplitButton`, but that's the only implementation I see when I search on Microsoft Docs. Your question lacks a good [mcve], and doesn't even provide _specific_ information about which class you're using.

Comment: @PeterDuniho   I'm using the "windows.ui.xaml.controls.togglesplitbutton" (but now I tried also the "microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.togglesplitbutton" and nothing has changed... the error displayed is always the same).   What does it mean that the property has to be a dependency property??  I've always created the twoway binding properties in that way, for almost 5 years now, and they have always worked! There has to be something wrong in the code of the control itself, if it can't accept a normal property from binding!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, such backward incompatibilities are all by design in uwp. In legacy Windows (XP,7,8 etc.) model, Microsoft was responsible to make Windows compatible to the previous version. MS had to spend much time and money to achieve that. But now in [WaaS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-overview) model, Microsoft will keep on updating Windows quite frequently and casually as you know. It's practically impossible for them to keep their products backward-compatible over the perpetual major-updates. So instead of MS, all uwp app developers are fatefully responsible to make their apps compatible to the latest version of Windows10.

Now, you are engaged in uwp development. If you hope your app can work on the current version of Windows10, just use DependencyProperty as it says. Or otherwise if you want for them to fix such a "feature" in future release, send feedbacks to them.

BTW, it may be also good for you to test your apps on [Insider Preview versions of OS/SDK](https://insider.windows.com/) to check whether your apps/codes will work in the forthcoming version of Windows, if you'd like to avoid similar troubles.

Comment: 3 hours ago I sent an issue on the microsoft xaml ui github repository and they answered that that really was a bug and that they are shipping a new version for this xaml control supporting even binding.  It will be available really soon.  Everything is solved.

Comment: That sounds great. I'd like to give you a rarest lucky uwp developer badge, if there were such a thing.